# Use mod_rewrite to delete ?category_id=xx from URLs

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, seo

I would like to use mod_rewrite to delete ?category_id=xx from all URLs on my page, with xx being a random number >= 1.

**Example:**

```
http://mypage.com/product-123.html?category_id=76
should become ...
http://mypage.com/product-123.html
```

Thanks a lot for your help,
David

Answer (score 1):

The query string (question mark and following parameters) is not part of the URL, so `RewriteRule`s don't include them.

Following [httpd's documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString), you can exclude the query string by matching something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/page /page?
```

In your case, I think the pattern can be:

```
RewriteRule    ^/product-([0-9]+)(\.html)    /product-$1.html?
```